# How to refresh a browser tap after time.sleep in python

Tags: python, browser

So this is what I'm using to open the browser

```
import webbrowser
import time

url = "http://google.com"
time = 5

def TestBrowse(url,time):
    webbrowser.open(url)
    time.sleep(time)
```

I want a function or method following time.sleep that will refresh the tab that the function opens. This is a module I'm just getting familiar with so I don't even know if its a better module or solution for this (or if at all possible)

Infact my main target was to be able to close the tab but I've been reading there is no way to do that, If this is false I would also love knowing how to do that. I've experimented with using os.system to kill the browser but os.system never seems to work inside a function (and It doesn't seem like a good idea anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) would be a better option for browser programing.
It accepts python scripts.

Also, you could try creating a wrapper web page with an embedded script that does the refreshing and/or exiting, though the browser might threat it as a cross-site scripting and limit the functionality of the URL you are trying to access. In any case to use that you would need to program in javascript rather than python.

Comment: how would i install that, i know it says use pip but I've never installed that package on this computer so I'm not even sure how to install that, my google search seems to return alot of 'outdated' methods

Comment: Reading the documentation[1] should be the way to go in this case.
But if you want to trust my memory there are at least 2 ways to use selenium. One is the firefox plugin. You install it like any other firefox plugin and program in it(inside firefox).
You can also install the server and python client API. After doing that you can start the server and program using the API like you would do with a normal python code.

[1] - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/